# Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql//10.0.1.86/mp_gws'

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jar, jmeter

SO I am trying to connect to Mysql through JMeter and this error comes up everytime. I am using Mysql through VPN and while running the test plan I am already logged in into VPN. I have already added the jar to lib folder of JMeter and the path to the jar file to Test plan. Please Help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Add the jar file with latest version and give proper path in jdbc connection configuration. as `jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.00:3306/db_name`. Using this connection configuration fixes the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is malformed, according to [Driver/Datasource Class Names, URL Syntax and Configuration Properties for Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) it should be something like:

```
jdbc:mysql://[host1][:port1][,[host2][:port2]]...[/[database]][?propertyName1=propertyValue1[&propertyName2=propertyValue2]...]
```

So you need to amend your JDBC URL to:

```
jdbc:mysql://10.0.1.86:3306/mp_gws
```

Also make sure you have [Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) jar somewhere in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath). Make sure you restart JMeter to pick the .jar up.

Check out [MySQL Database and JMeter - How to Test Your Connection](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mysql-database-and-jmeter-how-to-test-your-connection) article for more detailed steps if required.

Comment: I changed the JDBC URL and already had the connector Jar in Jmeter classpath. Now while running JMeter throws the following error : 

                               2017-11-27 15:20:02,875 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.isValid(I)Z
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:918) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:283) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
 at